# Order of WindowHandles

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm encountering an issue where WebDriver seems to change the order of WindowHandles.  This causes us to close the wrong one intermittently after getting them in some cases.

What seems to happen is the previously established first window handle is returned as a subsequent handle, which causes my logic to of course, close the wrong one.

Is WebDriver supposed to return the window handles in the same order every time (order of first opened window to last?).  This is what I initially expected, but now I'm not so sure.

I should also mention the problem seems to only occur in IE right now, but I'm not certain if this is a more generic issue.

Here is how I'm closing the active window and switching back to the root window.

```
public void Close()
        {
            //switch to latest window
            string windowName = string.Empty;
            if (_driver.WindowHandles.Count > 1)
            {
               //get 'root' window in list
                windowName = _driver.WindowHandles[0];
                _driver.Close();
                _driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowName);
            }
            else
            {
                _driver.Close();
            }
        }
```

We're on WebDriver 2.45 (C# bindings, 32-bit IEDriver).  If there is a method to close the active window in the C# bindings that would most likely solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pop up window handler is entirely unordered as per my understanding. I remember having same conversation on SO and luckily JimEvans(one of the contributors of `Selenium`) chimed in and clarify few factors. I read about the `PopupWindowFinder` of `Selenium`  .NET bindings and found that class can make your life lot easier. API is [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_PopupWindowFinder.htm). However, the whole order issue is entirely complex and painful to deal with. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers) thread. Just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks.  I was unaware of this class.