# Cannot switch to new window using Selenium Webdriver using switchTo()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have searched and searched for an answer to this question. I am testing in IE8 using Selenium Webdriver and C#. At a certain point in the test I am required to click a button that will then open up a new application window with forms that need to be filled out to continue the test.

I have tried:

```
driver.switchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
driver.switchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]); //this one usually returns and error
driver.switchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

I have also tried

```
foreach(String handle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
     driver.switchTo().Window(handle);
     //do things here
}
```

Each one fails and when I write the handle name to the console the outputs are all the same window name no matter what I try to do. Does anyone have an idea as to how I can get the new window?

Adding on to question:

Thank you @Saifur for the new direction with using PopupWindowFinder.

This is what I have tried with it so far

```
string currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
string popWindow = finder.Click(driver.FindElementById("Element"));
driver.SwitchTo().Window(popWindow);
```

So this is supposed to click on the element that will begin the popup event and then the switch should place it on the popup window so I can continue the test. Here is the problem now. When the `Element` is clicked by `finder` the app I am testing on creates one popup, then that popup window is closed, then another popup appears then that is closed and finally the actual app I need to test on appears and is either the current focus on the monitor or behind the initial page that started all of this.

So How can I get to the app window I need to test on? I have tried to switch onto the different popup windows that appear to try and jump it to the app window, but that did not work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `PopupWindowFinder ` class since you are using `C#`. And, see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774029/order-of-windowhandles/28774212#28774212)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful, It works charm:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

//To open new tab
js.ExecuteScript("window.open()");
ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(driver.WindowHandles);

//Switch driver to new tab
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);

//Close new tab
driver.Close();

//Switch driver to old tab
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```