# can not switch to a new page using python selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, url, python-requests

I need to scrape the CSV result of the website (https://requestmap.webperf.tools/). But I can’t.

This is the process I need to do:

1- load the website (https://requestmap.webperf.tools/)

2- enter a new website as an input (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/)

3- click submit

4- in the new page which opens after the submit, download the csv file at the end of the page

But I think the driver has the main page and doesn’t switch to the new page. That's why I can’t download the CSV file.

Would you please tell me how to do it?
here is my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://requestmap.webperf.tools/")


driver.find_element_by_id("url").send_keys("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("submitter").click()
```

I have tested different ways to solve my issue:
First of all:
I got this code from [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/how-to-proceed-after-clicking-a-link-to-new-page-in-selenium-in-python) :
But it doesn't work.

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]                           
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

I also tried [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13036/how-can-i-switch-to-the-new-instance-of-browser-in-python-selenium-webdriver) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809580/cannot-switch-to-new-window-using-selenium-webdriver-using-switchto), but they are not working as well.

```
# wait to make sure there are two windows open
# it is not working
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 2)

# switch windows
# it is not working
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
driver.find_elements_by_name("Download CSV")
```

So How can I get this issue solved?

Is there any other way in python to do so and switch to a new windows?