# Navigate driver to new opened window in selenium with C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a simple code to submit a sign up form with Selenium. Before submit, driver should come from home page to sign up page.

```
var firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mywebsite/home");
```

**If I print `firefox.Title`, it shows me title of home page currectly**

And in home page, there is a sign-up button. Sign up button link is bellow.

```
<a target="_blank" href="SignUp.jsp">Register Here</a>
```

To navigate to sign up page, I wrote a line:

```
firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='SignUp.jsp']")).Click();
```

After this, driver shows me the sign up page in `new window` of `firefox` browser. To navigate driver to the sign up I wrote `firefox.Navigate();`

Now **If I print `firefox.Title`, it shows me title of home page again**.

Please help me to find out problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
firefox.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
```

where `handle` is one of instances found in `firefox.WindowHandles`.  This will switch between the different window instances.  You can find more information in the docs for [`IWebDriver.SwitchTo()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much grabbing the same `title` since the you never switched to newly opened **window**

```
// Get the current window handle so you can switch back later.
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// Find the element that triggers the popup when clicked on.
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='webtraffic_popup_start_button']"));

// The Click method of the PopupWindowFinder class will click
// the desired element, wait for the popup to appear, and return
// the window handle to the popped-up browser window. Note that
// you still need to switch to the window to manipulate the page
// displayed by the popup window.
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(element);

driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);

// Do whatever you need to on the popup browser, then...
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

And, after switching to new window you should get new title.

However, this window handles process is utterly confusing to me. `Selenium` `.Net` bindings provide [PopupWindowFinder](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_PopupWindowFinder.htm) class to handle windows.

Gratitude to JimEvans for his nice works and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers)