# Operation timeout after switching back from popup window to main window

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, popup, webdriver, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit with the Selenium2 extension.

I'm opening a popup window, entering data and hit the submit button - after that the popup window closes.

Later then I'm switching back to the main window - all that works flawlessly. But after switching back no other steps of my tests are executed and the test fails with the following error message:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_NoSeleniumException: Error connection[28] to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/d6977d2b-76ac-4754-9a08-5119413b0965/element/4/submit: Operation timed out after 60004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

For the sake of completeness the code:

```
$windowHandles = $this->windowHandles();

$this->window($windowHandles[1]);

$this->byCssSelector('input[id=email]')->value($fbUsername);
$this->byCssSelector('input[id=pass]')->value($fbPassword);
$this->byCssSelector('input[id=u_0_1]')->submit();

$this->window($windowHandles[0]);
```

Did I miss some required step? Do I have to wait for something? Any pointers would help.

Comment: just a guess, though not worked on phpunit, can u try with `$this->window($this->windowHandles());`

Answer (score 2):

@akluth, a bug was discovery and will be fix. You can see more information [here](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/339). I'm waiting for a new release.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a `PHP` guy but I hope the following code will give you some ideas how to handle this. Note: the following is C# code

```
//You probably missing this the concept of handling current and original handle
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
ReadOnlyCollection<string> originalHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

// Cause the pop-up to appear
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='webtraffic_popup_start_button']")).Click();

// WebDriverWait.Until<T> waits until the delegate returns
// a non-null value for object types. We can leverage this
// behaviour to return the pop-up window handle.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
string popupWindowHandle = wait.Until<string>((d) =>
{
    string foundHandle = null;

    // Subtract out the list of known handles. In the case of a single
    // pop-up, the newHandles list will only have one value.
    List<string> newHandles = driver.CurrentWindowHandles.Except(originalHandles).ToList();
    if (newHandles.Count > 0)
    {
        foundHandle = newHandles[0];
    }

    return foundHandle;
});

driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);

// Do whatever you need to on the pop-up browser, then...
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

As, you said all that works flawlessly. But after switching back no other steps of my tests are executed and the test fails 
because the you have not correctly switch back to the original window handle.

This code is copy pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers)
Thanks @JimEvans for explaning this process.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your browser is upgraded. You need to update your selenium libraries accordingly.

Comment: What did you base this *guess* on?

Comment: @SiKing I have encountered "Operation timed out after" may times when my FF browser is upgraded due to auto update enabled. In that case I used to uninstall and install previous version/ upgrade my selenium libraries. Most of the times it solves my problem.