# Handle a popup window with selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I try to automate a download on a webpage using selenium. When I click on a button, a blank popup appears. After about 60 seconds a link appears on that popup. I would like to click on that link. Here is the code I've been using :

```
 //the button that makes the popup appear
 element = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame).FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='smenu']/input[@value='Imprimer']"));
 //I save the current handle so that I can get back to it later
 currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
 //the finder is supposed to return the handle of the popup
 PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
 string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(element);

 driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);
 //I wait for the link to appear on the popup
 driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body[@class='pop']/descendant::a[@href='/ppm/display_pdf.do']")).Click();
 driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
```

Here is the html code of the popup :

```
<body class=pop onunload=closePopup();>
    <table class=table height="90%" align=center>
        <tbody>
            <tr class=center height="30%">
                <td rowSpan=”1” colSpan=”1”>
                    <a href="/ppm/display_pdf.do">Eng_X82.pdf </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </body>
    </table>
```

But nothing happens, I can't seem to select the link to click on it. Do you see any mistake in my code ?

Comment: shouldn't your html say class="pop" (using quotation marks)? did you copy and paste or write it yourself?

Comment: hi, it's a combination of a couple copy and paste. I use the ' somewhere else in my code and it works

Comment: my advice: better be as exact as possible, otherwise helping you is extremely different because there are many ways to make a mistake, we need to rule out as many as possible in the first place

Comment: Ok, that's a good advice ! I use the code found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers  (the "alternative way" of the top answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this.

```
Alert aBox =driver.switchTo().alert(); 
aBox.accept();
```

To click on OK of the pop up

```
Alert aBox =driver.switchTo().alert(); 
            aBox.dismiss();
```

To click on Cancel of the pop up

Comment: Unfortunately it did not click the link. Do you know if I can select a window thanks to its url ?

Comment: Alerts are browser dialogs, not HTML dialogs like he is referring to. Alerts don't have links.

Comment: True what @JeffC said. The code will work on alerts. It is the basic syntax for handling alerts. If it is a window based pop up, you will have to use AutoIT