# How to verify click to call browser functionality with selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage where it contains 1300 number and i just need to verify that once i click on that link then it will open browser Popup window and i can capture the details from that popup and verify test is passed.

I need to do it for Website . Please help me with how to verify that popup.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @Buaban Well i need to know how can i do that ? I havent written any code yet .

Comment: @Buaban I would say that is browser popup window opens up for Which application to use for call.

Comment: You need to spend some time reading some tutorials and googling your question. Once you do that and try some things code-wise, if you get stuck then come back and ask a specific question, show what you've researched and coded, and what problem you are having.

Comment: @JeffC i've done googling and could not find anything for my specific question.My question was specific as well. Now in terms of trying the thing i needed the help for from where to start  and that was my question.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort at all in your question. You haven't shown any code you have attempted nor the HTML of the page and popup. I don't know how you expect us to help you in any useful way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1.Store window handle id of first window.

2.Store collecion of link elements

3.Iterate the collection

3.1 Click the element

3.2 Find the new window

3.3 Switch to the new window

3.4 Assert content

3.5 Switch back to the window handle id of first window (which is store at #1)

See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

1. Create driver object

   var IEBrowser = new InternetExplorerDriver();
2. Open URL

   ActionHelper.Timeout_Code(() => IEBrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl(URLTOWEBSITE), 15000, () => IEBrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl(URLTOWEBSITE));
3. Verify Popup page by selecting any control from popup.