# Code is not getting executable after opening pop up in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please find below the code :

```
d.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).clear();
d.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("polarissupport@polaristest.net");
Thread.sleep(2000);
d.findElement(By.name("txtTempBox")).clear();
Thread.sleep(2000);
d.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("password");
d.findElement(By.id("btnsubmit")).click();


Thread.sleep(2000);
d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoAdmin")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkContinue")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);


//GC Inbox

String s1 = "CHR-665";//d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblrequestidtext")).getText(); //For taking Request Id
String tem[] = s1.split("-");
d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCommonInbox_txtGrantID")).sendKeys(tem[1]);
d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCommonInbox_lnkSearch")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
d.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCommonInbox_grdAdminGrantCHR_ctl00_ctl04_btnAction")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkReleasePayment']")).click();
```

After the last line which opens the Pop-up, code is not getting executable to handle this opened Pop-up.
Please find below the code through which I handled the Pop-up:

```
String MainWindow=d.getWindowHandle();      
Set<String> set=d.getWindowHandles();       
Iterator<String> it=set.iterator();     

while(it.hasNext())         
{       
    System.out.println("Inside While");
    String ChildWindow=it.next();       

    if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))           
    {               
            d.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);       


            d.close();      
    }       
}
System.out.println("Outside While");
    d.switchTo().window(MainWindow);
```

Please let me know how to execute Pop-up handling code when Pop-up is opened because when I close the Pop-up manually then only this Pop-up handling code executes not at the time when Pop-up is opened.

Please let me know if question doesn't provide satisfactory information.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the pop up image? are you sure the pop up is not windows based?

Comment: @ChanChow: Yeah I'm sure that it is not windows based as URL is there into the Popup.By the way I'm not able to post image here so please let me know how to post that here if you want to see pop-up image.                             Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Alert` class or `PopupWindowFinder` Code in the link is based on c#, i hope you can convert it to your desired language easily
[popup's in selenium webdrivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I found the solution as I put the below code before .click() :                                                                                                             ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.showModalDialog = window.open;");                                                                                               which will call window.open instead of window.showModalDialog.