# Accessing a element in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

In Firebug I have a link with this content:

```
<a id="fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole" class="cb_or_somename cb_area_0219" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'$(this).attr(\'disabled\', \'disabled\');return true;','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'fwMainContentForm\'),{\'fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole\':\'fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole\'},\'\')');return false" href="#">Somename</a>
```

How can I use a "classname" to access the link (clicking on it)?

I have tried the following:

```
   WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_or_somename cb_area_0219"));
```

But I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector cb_or_somename cb_area_0219 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
>   The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

Answer (score 0):

`cb_or_somename cb_area_0219` is actually two classes. `By.className` can receive one of them

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_or_somename"));
// or
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_area_0219"));
```

If you want to locate the element with both of them use `cssSelector`

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cb_or_somename.cb_area_0219"));
```

Comment: ok, but can I tell Selenium to use both of them for one webelement?

Comment: @MagnusJensen Use `cssSelector`, its in my answer.

Comment: I did, but got the error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (181.5, 10.216659545898438). Other element would receive the click: <p class="environtment-banner" style="background-color: #004EFF; color: #FFF;"></p>
Command duration or timeout: 61 milliseconds

Comment: @MagnusJensen You have a banner or popup covering the button, you need to close it first. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608921/popups-in-selenium-webdrivers

Comment: Wierd, because I do not see a pop-up window. Tried out driver.switchTo().parentFrame(); and driver.switchTo().defaukltFrame(); right before the call for WebElement ... But no luck

Comment: @MagnusJensen its not a `frame`, its an element with class `environtment-banner`. Try to dismiss it with `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`

Comment: @MagnusJensen If this doesn't work you can try `JavaScript` `driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("arguments[0].click();", rolle);`

Comment: I am not sure this is the way to go because if I choose to say:   WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_or_somename")); it actually works and the link is being clicked. So no pop-up. The challenge is that there are 10+ links on the page with this class (cb_or_somename) I need to click at a spesific one, namely the one with (cb_area_0219)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132161/discussion-between-guy-and-magnus-jensen). @MagnusJensen

Answer (score 0):

To find element using both classes you can use the xpath instead of className.

```
 WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'cb_or_somename cb_area_0219')]"));
```